# How to use "cross apply" when parsing xml?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

Trying to parse multiple xml files.
But stack in applying cross apply

First variant works fine

```
DECLARE @input XML = 

'<a>
    <b>
     <g>one</g>
    <n>
        <c>somedata1 1</c>
    </n>
    <n>
        <c>2somedata 2</c>
    </n>
</b>
</a>'       

SELECT
g                   = XC.value('(g)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
i                   = xc1.n1.value ('(c)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM @input.nodes ('a/b') as XT (XC)
cross apply @input.nodes ('//n') as xc1(n1)
```

second variant fails (returns empty fields) - I know this is becouse absence of <с> nodes

```
DECLARE @input XML = 
'<a>
    <b>
     <g>one</g>
        </b>
</a>'
SELECT
    g                   = XC.value('(g)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    i                   = xc1.n1.value ('(c)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM @input.nodes ('a/b') as XT (XC)
cross apply @input.nodes ('//n') as xc1(n1)
```

I working with multiple files, and some of them have those nodes and some no, what is my decision supposed to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In second case you don't have any `n` element. You need to use [`OUTER APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> There are two forms of APPLY: CROSS APPLY and OUTER APPLY. CROSS APPLY
>   returns only rows from the outer table that produce a result set from
>   the table-valued function. **OUTER APPLY returns both rows that produce
>   a result set, and rows that do not, with NULL values in the columns
>   produced by the table-valued function.**

```
DECLARE @input XML = 
'<a>
    <b>
     <g>one</g>
        </b>
</a>';

SELECT g = XC.value('(g)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
       i = xc1.n1.value ('(c)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM @input.nodes ('a/b') AS XT (XC)
OUTER APPLY @input.nodes ('//n') AS xc1(n1);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/OJEJI12691)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦══════╗
║  g  ║  i   ║
╠═════╬══════╣
║ one ║ NULL ║
╚═════╩══════╝
```